# Managing Fields Tips

Tags: entities, database

My database is getting way out of hand with respect to field_data... and field_revision...

is there any tricks in managing fields, seems really odd design method to me, I have over 100 tables just for fields alone.

I have tried to reuse the same field multiple time, but you cant use the same field more than once in the one content type.

ideally i would just have a field for each different data type and not every single field.

Comment: Are you using Drupal 6 or 7?

Comment: i am using drupal 7

Answer (score 1):

How exactly is it going out of hand? Unless you have some kind of maximum number of tables you're allowed to have, 100 tables aren't really a problem. It's like this because this is the only way support multiple values per field.

The field storage system is pluggable, you can for example also use [MongoDB](http://drupal.org/project/mongodb) to store your fields. The advantage of that is that it can store a complete content type in a single "document" and retrieve it with a single lookup/fetch. The downside is, you have to manage/maintain a second database server (and be able to so, which you aren't on shared webhosting for example).

See also [The truth about field storage in Drupal 7](http://drupal4hu.com/node/268). As linked from there, there is also a [Per bundle storage](http://drupal.org/project/pbs) project, but development stopped. Looks like nobody cares enough about this to maintain that module.

Comment: I don't agree with most of the design decisions in drupal, most of all the way fields are managed. Yeah i can add db tables all day if i like but when it comes to clean db structure drupal is terrible. I just want to make the best of a bad design and was hoping someone had some tips on managing their fields. Like for instance, can i turn off revisions? i have no plan to use them? can i turn off multi language support etc.

Comment: You can't with the default implementation but you are free to write your own field storage backend which does it different. But always creating those those tables and additional columns is the only way to support being able to change your mind and enable revisions of content types at some point. If you don't use revisions, that table will stay empty, so it really doesn't care. That is a general downside of using a CMS/framework like Drupal. There is a lot of code/data/tables/.. that might be overhead for you/your project but is required by others.